# Insert conflict

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio

I am developing a WPF C# application and I am encountering the following exception when trying to insert data into my database:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__VotacaoVa__JuriI__43D61337". The conflict occurred in database "Seriacao", table "dbo.Juri", column 'ID'. The statement has been terminated

The functions I am using to insert data into my database are as follows:

```
private void LerDadosFicheiroJuri(string CaminhoFicheiro, int id) 
{
   StreamReader rf = new StreamReader(CaminhoFicheiro);
   string stringComando = string.Format("INSERT INTO Juri(Nome,Sobrenome,VotacaoID) values(@Nome, @Sobrenome, @VotacaoID)");

   SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(stringComando, baseDeDados);
   comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", "");
   comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sobrenome", "");
   comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VotacaoID", id);

   using (rf) 
   { 
      while (!rf.EndOfStream) 
      {
         var line = rf.ReadLine();
         string[] campos = line.Split(',');

         comando.Parameters["@Nome"].Value = campos[0];
         comando.Parameters["@Sobrenome"].Value = campos[1];

         comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }
   rf.Close();
}

private void LerDadosFicheiroCandidato(string CaminhoFicheiro, int id) 
{
   StreamReader rf = new StreamReader(CaminhoFicheiro);
   string stringComando = string.Format("SELECT Nome FROM Votacao");
   SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(stringComando, baseDeDados);
   SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

   using (rf) 
   {
      if (reader.HasRows) 
      {
         while (!rf.EndOfStream) 
         {
            reader.Close();
            var line = rf.ReadLine();
            string[] campos = line.Split(',');

            stringComando = string.Format("INSERT INTO Candidato(Nome,Sobrenome,VotacaoID,Idade) values('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')",
            campos[0], campos[1], id, Convert.ToInt32(campos[2]));
            comando = new SqlCommand(stringComando, baseDeDados);
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
      }
   }
   rf.Close();
}

private void LerDadosFicheiroValores(string CaminhoFicheiro, int ncandidatos, int njuris, int IDJuri, int IDCandidato) 
{
   StreamReader rf = new StreamReader(CaminhoFicheiro);
   string stringComando = string.Format("SELECT Nome FROM Votacao");
   SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(stringComando, baseDeDados);

   SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

   using (rf) 
   {
      if (reader.HasRows) 
      {
         while (!rf.EndOfStream) 
         {
            reader.Close();
            var line = rf.ReadLine();
            string[] campos = line.Split(',');

            for (int j = 0; j < njuris; j++) 
            {
               for (int i = 0; i < ncandidatos; i++) 
               { 
                  stringComando = string.Format("INSERT INTO VotacaoValores(JuriID,Valor,Pontuacao,CandidatoID) values('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')",
                  IDJuri+j, Convert.ToInt32(campos[2 + i]), Convert.ToInt32(campos[9 + i]), IDCandidato+i);
                  comando = new SqlCommand(stringComando, baseDeDados);
                  comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
            }
         }     
      }
   }
   rf.Close();
}
```

My database has the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Juri 
(
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Nome VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    Sobrenome VARCHAR(60),
    VotacaoID INTEGER NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (VotacaoID) REFERENCES Votacao(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Candidato 
(
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Nome VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    Sobrenome VARCHAR(60),
    VotacaoID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Idade INTEGER NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (VotacaoID) REFERENCES Votacao(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE VotacaoValores 
(
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    JuriID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Valor INT NOT NULL,
    Pontuacao INT NOT NULL,
    CandidatoID INT NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (JuriID) REFERENCES Juri(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CandidatoID) REFERENCES Candidato(ID)
);
```

The function `LerDadosFicheiroCandidato` and `LerDadosFicheirojuri` work correctly and insert the data into the database correctly. When I run `LerDadosFicheiroValores`, I get the error indicating that I am trying to insert data into the `VotacaoValores` table that does not exist in the `juri` table.

Comment: Always test your queries inside SQL Server Management Studio before using in another app.  The error messages inside SSMS are much better than in c#.

Comment: When i go see my database the data on table "juri" and "candidato" its correct and when i use a inser into VotacaoValores on SQL Server Management Studio the data enter correctly on the table but on visual studio appear the error

Comment: What makes you think that the id `JuriID` can have a value `IDJuri+j` ? Same question goes for `CandidatoID` and `IDCandidato+i`

Comment: These paramters are passed by a function who gets the first ID associated to a Votacao, so if i get the first entry ID on the databse to that votation with the cycle for knowing how many Candidato and Juri a Votacao have i can get the others id (because its auto incremented)

Comment: IDs are not necessarily consecutive, there could be gaps in between

Comment: the way i'm adding yes there are consecutive and i'm checking everytime if that is correctly and yes it is! Also the function "LerDadosFicheiroJuri" is working well so always gets at least 1 Juri on the database so if the function "LerDadosFicheiroValores" works at least he put always 1 row with data on the table

Comment: Check the log files by using SSMS under Management in the explorer.  The log files should show a more detail error that one you are getting from c#.

Comment: The logs dont say i have an error

Comment: *"the way i'm adding yes there are consecutive "* where? You're using an `IDENTITY`; that isn't consecutive.

Comment: You're also using injection, a fatal security flaw; **parameterise**.

Comment: Can you help em with the parameterise?
And until that day i add as many Juri or Candidato i want the id is consecutive and that dont fail me until now

Comment: You should use dapper. It'll make command parameters easier. The error is telling you that the value you pass for that foreign key doesn't match any Id in the table it references. Looks like your insert to juri has a votacoid doesn't match an Id in votaco.

Comment: @jdweng SQL Server doesn't record this sort of error in the error log so a waste of time looking there. The SQL Server error log holds system information and info on high severity errors or things explicitly logged to it. Not routine standard severity application errors

Comment: Hello. If you confirm that there is no problem with your sql execution in SSM, and only in Visual Studio, then there may be a problem with your database connection string. And from the error message alone, the id as a foreign key does not have this value in other tables